# Non-orthogonal projection onto subspace along other subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I have a problem with the following exercise:

Find the projection of a vector $v=[-2, 0, 2, 2, 0]^{T}$ onto subspace $V = span\{[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]^{T}, [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]^{T}\}$  along subspace $W = span\{[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]^{T}, [0, 0, 3, 2, 1]^{T}, [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]^{T}\}$.

To be honest I don't know what exactly should I do. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Do you know ho to find the projection of the vector $[3, 5]$ onto the $x$-axis via projection along the span of $[1, 1]$?

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a vector $v'\in V$ such that $v-v'\in W$.

So, first you should confirm that $V\oplus W=\Bbb R^5$, which follows if the 5 given generator elements form a basis $B$.

Then find the unique decomposition $v=v'+w$ with $v'\in V,\, w\in W$. (This becomes easy if you find the coordinates of $v$ with respect to basis $B$.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Let me check If I've understood you correctly. First of all, I check that $V+W = V \oplus W$, which means that a given set of vectors are linearly independent. Then, I find the coordinates of $v$ in this basis: $v= b_1 - b_2 -b_3+b_4-b_5,$ where $b_1 = [-1,1,2,3,4]^{T}$, $b_2 = [0,0,1,2,3]^{T}$, $b_3 = [1,1,1,1,1]^{T}$, $b_4 = [0,0,3,2,1]^{T}$, $b_5 = [0,0,1,0,1]^{T}$. Finally, I found that $v^{\prime}= b_1 -b_2-2b_3-2b_5$. Is that correct? The very last question, what should I do in order to find an operator of this projection?

Comment: Supposed your coordinates are correct and $v=(b_1-b_2)+(-b_3+b_4-b_5)$, then it already provides the decomposition and $v'=b_1-b_2$. To obtain the matrix of the projection operator (in the standard basis), just calculate $v'$ for each standard basis vector $v=e_1,\dots, e_5$ and write them in the columns. Alternatively, using basis transformation, it should be equal to $B^{-1}\pmatrix{1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0}B where the elements of the basis $B$ are put as columns in matrix $B$.